# html css - vertical-alignment inside button - how to get it on top?

Tags: html, css, button

I got the following situation:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2dBE5/)

```
<button type="submit">
    <div class="icon"></div>
</button>

button {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background: orange;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.icon {
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    height: 80px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background: pink;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

I want the div inside a button at the top.
If I use negative top the other element inside the button are not exact after the first div element. if i set the icon-div with vertical-align top nothing happens.

Why is it always in the middle? how can i get this on top?
If i use an a-tag instead of a button with the same rules i does not get this problem.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to put `<div>` inside of a `<button>`, it's not a valid document.

Replace `<button>` with `<div>` and then it works as expected ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qcpuR/)):

```
<div type="submit">
    <div class="icon"></div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
div[type="submit"] {   // Only change here, to properly match div instead of a button
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background: orange;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.icon {
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    height: 80px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background: pink;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: no, I also need the button-tag as requested! it should be the same with button-tag or a-tag oder div-tag. now I had to use position absolute of the icon :-(

Answer (score 0):

I got two ways let me know if those work

```
.icon{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 45px;
}
```

or

```
.icon{
position: relative;
top: -85px;
}
```